# How to get time from database?

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a very old app that needs to move to a new server and I have a query that looks like this.

```
"SELECT JOB_ID FROM Jobs WHERE PostingStatus='A' && ListEnd >= ".time();
```

not sure hot to replace the `.time();` section with something that will work the same in a newer version of SQL.

There is a `ListEnd` column and its has data that looks like this `1207775971`. What the query needs to do is by my understanding is that it gets all Active jobs that are `>=` to the last `ListEnd`. But I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: What RDMS are you using?

Comment: @JohnConde SQL apparently. But not the newest version.

Comment: Im sorry John i am very new to this what is RMDS?

Comment: Relational Database Management System....MySQL, Postgres, etc.

Comment: MySQL its says version 5.5.37

Comment: mamdouh, can you give me an example of I would use now().

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`".time()` is not sql. It is PHP and it returns the timestamp (seconds passed since 1 Januari 1970), which is then added to the query.

The mysql equivalent is unix_timestamp, so you can change the above with `unix_timestamp()"`.

But why would you? Both functions still work in newer versions. And if you change it, the the system time of your db server (if hosted on an other machine) will become leading, in stead of your webserver.

Furthermore, what the query does is get all jobs that have a ListEnd set in the future.

PS. When migrating to the new server, do check if the new server has the same time settings (time zone).

Comment: Yes, do check the server.  However, the nice thing about unix timestamps is that they're time zone independent, so that's not too much of a worry.

Comment: Thanks guys, will try it out and will let you know if that worked.

Comment: Using unix_timestamp() instead of time() did work for me, thanks guys.